# Question regarding algebra-valued models for set theory

Tags: set-theory

Suppose you have the following algebra $4={1, a, b, 0}$  such that $0≤b≤a≤1$. Now we define the model $V^A$ by transfinite recursion. Conjunction and Disjunction are defined as usually as max and min. , whereas the implication is defined by $\neg (a \wedge \neg b)$ ( where $\neg$ is an intuitionistic negation). Can you come up with a sentence $\sigma$ in the language of set theory such that $[\sigma ] = b$ ?

Comment: Do you allow parameters in your sentence?

Comment: Dear Stefan, no parameters allowed ! (The result follows trivially if we allow parameters). I was thinking of the following sentence $\sigma = \exists x,y ( x= y \wedge \forall z (z \in x \wedge z \notin y))$. Do u think this could work ? The idea is that since the existential quantifier is a supremum, so we know that (x=y) = 1 , so z can not have a zero as its range, but then the smallest z that satisfies this property should have b as range and therefore the whole sentence $\sigma$ should receive b as its value ?

Answer (score 2):

Without parameters, this is impossible.

The reason is that you're dealing with a homogeneous forcing (there is a dense, homogeneous subposet in your algebra, namely $\{a,b,1 \}$) and for homogeneous forcings we have
$$
p \Vdash \phi \iff 1 \Vdash \phi
$$
for all $p \neq 0$ in your algebra. Now remember that
$$
\| \phi \| = \sup \{ p \mid p \Vdash \phi \}
$$
to conclude the claim.

Comment: Btw, there is no algebra as in your post: Neither $a$ nor $b$ have a complement in the poset that you've written down. But, regardless, if you write down a correct algebra, my answer applies as long as you have a dense, homogeneous subposet.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what an "intuitionistic negation" mean, but I suspect that it might generate some semblance of an algebra. Either in the Boolean sense, or at least in the Heyting sense.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, I don't know how to parse that either. But since this argument is so robust, it very likely doesn't matter. That's why I didn't ask for further clarification.